# from 4.5 to 4.0 :The type or namespace name 'AspNet' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-4.0

I was working on .Net 4.5 used SignalR 1.1.2 and everything works fine.
Then we want to lower the version of netframework to 4.0 cos of production server, everything stopped and this error appeared. Please tell me what to do?

```
The type or namespace name 'AspNet' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: I don't think you can.  Looking at MSDN, it looks like this is 4.5 assembly, with no earlier version. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr%28v=vs.111%29.aspx

Comment: try setting copy local to true for files

Comment: Apparently there is a set of libraries for 4.0 - it may be that you don't have those assemblies on your dev or build machine?

Comment: @KrishnaDhungana do that with no luck.

Comment: Tried to simulate your issue but I am getting different errors. I am searching possible issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved problem by removing reference from project then build. After failed Build Add reference. Working perfectly in .net 4.0.

We can also Uninstall then install nuGet Packages.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by deleting the contents of bin and obj folder on my project folder, then open the project and rebuild.